# Написать условие с минимальным использованием памяти

Tags: java, оптимизация, логика

```
 if (inputZ1 > inputZ2) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Z1 должен быть меньше Z2");
     SimpleGUI.inputX1.setText("");
     SimpleGUI.inputX2.setText("");
     SimpleGUI.inputZ1.setText("");
     SimpleGUI.inputZ2.setText("");
 }


JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (inputX1<inputX2) ? (inputZ1<inputZ2) ? "Строиться можно начиная с координат XZ:" + resultX + " " + resultZ : null : null);
```

Проблема в том что в случае inputZ1 > inputZ2 выводит сообщение *Z1 должен быть меньше Z2* а после этого выводиться пустое сообщение MessageDialog как сделать так что при условии inputZ1 > inputZ2 после вывода сообщения *Z1 должен быть меньше Z2* MessageDialog выводился только в случае

(inputX1 < inputX2) и (inputZ1 < inputZ2)?

Comment: А почему вы не хотите написать `else { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog...` ?

Comment: Можно поподробнее пожалуйста

Comment: if (inputZ1 > inputZ2) {
    ...
 } else {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Если inputX1 > inputX2 выведет тебе сообщение *X1 должен быть меньше X2*
2)Если inputZ1 > inputZ2 выведет тебе сообщение *Z1 должен быть меньше Z2*
3)Если inputX1 < inputX2 и inputZ1 < inputZ2 выведет тебе сообщение *Строиться можно начиная с координат XZ:*`resultX` `resultZ`

```
if (inputX1 > inputX2) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X1 должен быть меньше X2");
                    SimpleGUI.inputX1.setText("");
                    SimpleGUI.inputX2.setText("");
                    SimpleGUI.inputZ1.setText("");
                    SimpleGUI.inputZ2.setText("");
                }

                if (inputZ1 > inputZ2) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Z1 должен быть меньше Z2");
                    SimpleGUI.inputX1.setText("");
                    SimpleGUI.inputX2.setText("");
                    SimpleGUI.inputZ1.setText("");
                    SimpleGUI.inputZ2.setText("");
                }
                if ((inputX1 < inputX2) && (inputZ1 < inputZ2)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Строиться можно начиная с координат XZ:" + resultX + " " + resultZ);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

А как часто вызывается данное сравнение? Можете попробовать вот так:

```
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (inputZ1 > inputZ2 ? "Z1 должен быть меньше Z2" : "Строиться можно начиная с координат XZ:" + resultX + " " + resultZ).
```

но много вы на этом не сэкономите. Если вы часто вызываете это то лучше вынести сборку строк в переменные то можете попробовать так:

```
   private static String msg1 = "Z1 должен быть меньше Z2";
   private static String msg2Templ = "Строиться можно начиная с координат XZ:%s %s";
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (inputZ1 > inputZ2 ? msg1 : String.format(msg2Templ,resultX,resultZ ));
```

или так:

```
   private static String msg1 = "Z1 должен быть меньше Z2";
   private static String msg2Templ = "Строиться можно начиная с координат XZ:{0} {1}";
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (inputZ1 > inputZ2 ? msg1 : MessageFormat.format(msg2Templ,resultX,resultZ ));
```

В этих вариантах при многократном использовании вы не будете каждый раз заново создавать текстовые строки. Можно попробовать сделать соединение строк не через конкатенацию а через StringBuilder.

Comment: Решил использовать такое вариант:
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (inputX1<inputX2) ? (inputZ1<inputZ2) ? "Строиться можно начиная с координат XZ:" + resultX + " " + resultZ : null : null);
Есть проблема всё работает но если к примеру X1 или Z1 больше X2 или Z2 тогда мне пишет что Z1 должен быть меньше Z2 (так и должно быть) а потом выводиться пустое сообщение как избежать этого пустого сообщения MessageDialog

Comment: Так вы сами так написали. Если разложить ваше выражение, то получится `String msg = (inputZ1<inputZ2) ? "Строиться можно начиная с координат XZ:" + resultX + " " + resultZ : null`, `msg = (inputX1<inputX2) ? msg : null`, JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg). Соответственно при указанных вами условиях выдается `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, null)`. Поправьте логику

Comment: Мне в случае если я пишу так JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (inputZ1<inputZ2) ? (inputX1<inputX2) ? ("Строиться можно начиная с координат XZ:" + resultX + " " + resultZ); выдаёт ошибку : expected :expected ; expected

Comment: Я хотел написать что при (inputX1<inputX2) и (inputZ1<inputZ2) выдавалось сообщение "Строиться можно начиная с координат XZ:" + resultX + " " + resultZ

Comment: Это должно выглядеть так  ((inputX1<inputX2) && (inputZ1<inputZ2) ) ? msg1 : msg2

Comment: Если у вас msg2 не, то пишите через обычный `if((inputX1<inputX2) && (inputZ1<inputZ2) ) msg = msg1`

Comment: Спасибо появился новый вопрос
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1066459/joptionpane-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d1%91%d0%bc

Comment: Этот вопрос я так понимаю закрыт?

Comment: Данный вопрос закрыт