# JOptionPane и условия в нём

Tags: java, логика

Есть код который можно реализовать с JOptionPane

```
if (inputX1 > inputX2) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X1 должен быть меньше X2");
    SimpleGUI.inputX1.setText("");
    SimpleGUI.inputX2.setText("");
    SimpleGUI.inputZ1.setText("");
    SimpleGUI.inputZ2.setText("");
}

if (inputZ1 > inputZ2) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Z1 должен быть меньше Z2");
    SimpleGUI.inputX1.setText("");
    SimpleGUI.inputX2.setText("");
    SimpleGUI.inputZ1.setText("");
    SimpleGUI.inputZ2.setText("");
}
if ((inputX1 < inputX2) && (inputZ1 < inputZ2)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Строиться можно начиная с координат XZ:" + resultX + " " + resultZ);
}
```

Сейчас я понимаю так

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (inputZ1<inputZ2) ? (inputX1<inputX2) ? "1" : "2" : "3");

Если `(inputZ1<inputZ2) ? (inputX1<inputX2)` true выводиться 1

Если `(inputZ1<inputZ2)` true выводиться 2

Если `(inputX1<inputX2)` true выводиться 3
```

Мне нужно было сделать что при `(inputZ1<inputZ2) ? (inputX1<inputX2)` выводиться сообщение "Строиться можно начиная с координат XZ:" + resultX + " " + resultZ
И я вот сейчас не понимаю как сделать что бы

Если `(inputZ1<inputZ2)` true не выводилось 2

Если `(inputX1<inputX2)` true не выводилось 3

Я писал вместо 2 и 3 null выводилось пустое сообщение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
 String msg0 = "Строиться можно начиная с координат XZ:{0} {1}";
 String msg1 = "X1 должен быть меньше X2";
 String msg2 = "Z1 должен быть меньше Z2";

 if((inputX1 < inputX2) && (inputZ1 < inputZ2)){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, MessageFormat.format(msg0, resultX,  resultZ));
 } else if((inputX1 > inputX2) && (inputZ1 > inputZ2)){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg1 + " и " + msg2);
 } else if(inputX1 > inputX2){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg1);
 } else if(inputZ1 > inputZ2){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg2);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю следующую логику:

```
boolean doWeHaveError = false;
String message;

if(x1 >= x2) {
    doWeHaveError = true;
    //добавляйте нужное сообщение
}

if(z1 >= z2) {
    doWeHaveError = true;
    if(doWeHaveError){
       message += " и ";
    }
    //добавляйте нужное сообщение
}

if(!doWeHaveError) {
    //добавляйте нужное сообщение
}
```